# Have mails show up in main INBOX folder of Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, gmail

This is the first time I am using Outlook.

I added a mail account (Google Apps - Gmail) account to my Outlook. Although when I added the account, it created an entry in the left panel "All Mail Items" called "example@domain.com", which is fine.

Although I would like all the mails to come in the main "Inbox" folder and not just in "Inbox in example@domain.com"

How could I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could "Create a rule" to move the email to the main box when they come in. Choose a email from the account want to move and right click on it choosing "Rules" and then "Create Rule" click "Sent to" and choose the incoming email address. Then click "Move the item to folder" and choose the Inbox. I hope this helps.